# How to speed up search function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

I am using React (class component) and have created a search function. It does a good job in searching what I want, but sometimes it get unusable slow. The search component is triggered on input changes using onChange. The "bigData" state that is filtered is an array that always contains 9000 objects, each object consists of three properties.

As you can see I have tried to create throttle and it makes a huge difference, but still it can be really slow from time to time. For various reason I really don't want a search button, so that is not an option.

Any idea how to speed the search function up?

```js
 search = (event) => {
     const searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
     this.setState({ searchTerm: searchTerm });
     if(searchTerm.length < 2) {
         return;
     }
     // Clear any existing timer
     if(this.timer) {
         clearTimeout(this.timer);
     }
     // Set a new timer to delay the search by 800ms
     this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
         const exactMatchesName = this.state.bigData.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase() === searchTerm);
         if(exactMatchesName.length > 0) {
             this.setState({ matches: exactMatchesName })
             this.timer = null;
             return;
         }
         const allWords = searchTerm.split(' ');
         const containsAllWordsName = this.state.bigData.filter(item => allWords.every(word => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(word)));
         if(containsAllWordsName.length > 0) {
             this.setState({ matches: containsAllWordsName })
             this.timer = null;
             return;
         }
         const individualWordsName = searchTerm.split(' ');
         const oneWordMatchesName = this.state.bigData.filter(item =>
             individualWordsName.some(word => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(word))
         );
         this.setState({ matches: oneWordMatchesName })
         this.timer = null;
     }, 800);
 }
```

Comment: not sure if all those `item.name.toLowerCase()` could be the issue, but personally, I'd do a `this.state.bigData.forEach(item => item.lower = item.name.toLowerCase());` once every time `this.state.bigData` is populated/changed, then change all the `item.name.toLowerCase()` to `item.lower` - I doubt it'll make much difference however.

Comment: I noticed that you looped through a large array three times in order to find out if the array contained a certain value, so could you first sort the large array and then use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to quickly determine if the value existed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single loop with a shortcut for higher priority search results.

```
const
    searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase(),
    splitted = searchTerm.split(/\s+/),
    matches = [[], [], []];

let index = 2;

for (const item of bigData) {
    const name = item.name.toLowerString();

    if (name === searchTerm) {
        index = 0;
        matches[index].push(item);
    }
    if (index === 0) continue;

    if (splitted.every(w => name.includes(w)) {
        index = 1;
        matches[index].push(item);
    }
    if (index === 1) continue;

    if (splitted.some(w => name.includes(w)) {
        matches[index].push(item);
    }
}
// finally take matches[index]
```

Comment: works a little better but still very slow. I added throttle and also made som more changes which increased the speed more but still to slow. What I did was that i used trim() to the searchTerm, otherwise space was added to the last list of words. Also added a limit of 3 words. So after 3 no more is used in search. Still to slow though..

Comment: maybe changing to a classic loop with index would serve faster.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve it using index and set a maximum number of anwers.